# developing an infinite title slider with corresponding pageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

ok, I wanted to create these custom controls I've seen in this app:

[DownTown App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id908014422)

[image]

an infinite title slider above and an infinite page view controller below. you can scroll title infinitely and after scrolling finished, corresponding page controller scrolls to target viewController in that direction.
and you can can scroll the view controller below, and above titleSlider also scrolls with that.

so I create these components but the result is not exactly what I want, because there were some challenges I couldn't solve them. here you can download the component:
http://github.com/hashemp206/HAInfinitePageController

1. the first problem is as as I scroll titles, the target cell rest at center of view. but as I scroll faster and more you see the title is not resting at center and I have to manually move that cell to the center with animation.

to clarify how this title slider scrolls infinitely, I have created a UICollectionView with 3 section. when scrollView reaches an offset limit, I will jump back to the middle section.

2. the second problem is when I scroll the below pageController slowly, the above title slider moves well and correctly, but when I scroll faster this synchronization gets corrupted, and the title slider scroll can't synchronize itself with below page controller.

so I'm asking you expert guys, can you see my developed component and guess why it is not working well?

or if you want to **challenge yourself** can you develop this component exactly?

Comment: Hello my friend, I have downloaded your repo, and i found at least 3 crash to work with, you have experienced this as same as i do?

Comment: the project works well at the basic usage! I couldn't face those crashes. but if you scroll fast, app may crash. the component is buggy and it's best not try to fix it issues, I suggest look at my code and try to reDevelop it yourself and compare to DownTown. because our thoughts are different